# SQL queries results write to Excel

Tags: php, sql, excel

OK so I have no Idea how to do this except install PHPexcel

But say I have the results of a query in an array

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('server', 'user1', 'pass', 'users');
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
     die(connect error ('.$mysqli->connect_error.') '.$mysqli->connect_error);

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT * from usr WHERE date = '$date'";
while($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
     //EXCEL STUFF???
}
```

And then how would I write this to an excel spreadsheet?
Any help appreciated

Comment: have you ever used google?

Answer (score 2):

1st: you have a syntax error:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('server', 'user1', 'pass', 'users');
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
     die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT * from usr WHERE date = '$date'";

while($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
     //EXCEL STUFF???
}
```

2nd, you can output it as a normal table and add this in the header:

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xls");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

This script will automatically allow you to download a file named `abc.xls` with your content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHPExcel for writing to or reading from an Excel sheet.

Link: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Here is example code for reading/writing to Excel

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

//Minimum sample code from site:

```
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Add some data

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');

// Save Excel 2007 file

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```