# Exporting SQLite table to Excel using PHP script

Tags: php, excel, sqlite

I am working on a project and new to PHP and I need to know how to export the table data from SQLite to Excel.

I am able to do it from database but I do not know how to export to Excel using PHP.

```
<?php
$db = new sqlite3('I:\Preeti\explor\WebMobility.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM VerbaliData');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL queries results write to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131845/sql-queries-results-write-to-excel)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method whould be to write your results into a CSV file which opens in Excel in a readable format.

See here for more information: http://php.net/fputcsv

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks Beittil, It worked is it possible to add headers

Comment: Yeah, sure. You could use the same method to write a line with the names of the columns. You can either take these from the resultset, or write an array with custom headers to the CSV file. In this case you need to make sure that the array matches the amount of columns from the db.

Comment: Hi Beittil I tried it but its not working what code should i add more..  while ($row = $results->fetchArray(sqlite3_BOTH); can you help me with this please